# find the combinations of attributename and allowedvalues and set IsConflictValue to true if combination matches in C# linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var inputDto = new List<ChangeAssignmentDto> {
    new ChangeAssignmentDto { AssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    AssignmentHash = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    RoleId = Guid.Parse("50109670-BD0F-4531-8BE7-CBD12558CC02"),
                    UserId = Guid.Parse("61eed904-c044-4dcc-8eb5-6a590e4a3d0a"),
                    Attributes = new List<AttributeInfoDto>
                    {
                        new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Country",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "United Kingdom", IsCOnflict = false },
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "United States", IsCOnflict = false }
                        }
                    }, new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Attribute1",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "Item1", IsCOnflict = false },
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "Item2" , IsCOnflict = false} }
                    } } },

    new ChangeAssignmentDto { AssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    AssignmentHash = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    RoleId = Guid.Parse("50109670-BD0F-4531-8BE7-CBD12558CC02"),
                    UserId = Guid.Parse("61eed904-c044-4dcc-8eb5-6a590e4a3d0a"),
                    Attributes = new List<AttributeInfoDto>
                    { new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Country",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "United States", IsCOnflict = false } }
                    },new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Attribute1",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "Item1", IsCOnflict = false } }
                    } } } ,
    new ChangeAssignmentDto { AssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    AssignmentHash = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    
                    RoleId = Guid.Parse("50109670-BD0F-4531-8BE7-CBD12558CC02"),
                    UserId = Guid.Parse("61eed904-c044-4dcc-8eb5-6a590e4a3d0a"),
                    Attributes = new List<AttributeInfoDto>
                    { new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Country",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "Australia", IsCOnflict = false } }
                    },new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Attribute1",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "Item1", IsCOnflict = false } }
                    } } },
    new ChangeAssignmentDto { AssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    AssignmentHash = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    
                    RoleId = Guid.Parse("50109670-BD0F-4531-8BE7-CBD12558CC02"),
                    UserId = Guid.Parse("586e1a46-fef8-452a-b487-6012e538411d"),
                    Attributes = new List<AttributeInfoDto>
                    { new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Country",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "United States", IsCOnflict = false } }
                    },new AttributeInfoDto
                        {
                           AttributeName = "Attribute1",
                           AllowedValues = new List<AllowedValue> {
                           new AllowedValue { Value = "Item1", IsCOnflict = false } }
                    } } }
        };
```

For example: if input is passed as below the `isConflict` flag should be set to true

Input :

| # | Userid | Country | Attribute1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | U1 | US,UK | Item1, Item2 |
| 2 | U1 | US | Item1 |
| 3 | U1 | Australia | Item1 |
| 4 | U2 | US | Item6 |

Output:

| # | Userid | Country | Attribute1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | U1 | US(IsCOnflict true),UK | Item1(IsCOnflict true), Item2(IsCOnflict false) |
| 2 | U1 | US(IsCOnflict true) | Item1(IsCOnflict true) |
| 3 | U1 | Australia(IsCOnflict false) | Item1(IsCOnflict false) |
| 4 | U2 | US(IsCOnflict false) | Item6(IsCOnflict false) |

So for same `userId`, we would like to see if the combination is conflicting.

Like in the above example, 1 & 2 are conflicting with values U1 + US + Item1 of 1st Record and U1 + US + Item1 of 2nd record.

Can you please suggest an easier and efficient way to resolve this requirement?

Comment: Easier and efficient compared to what? LINQ is for querying data / creating new objects, not for modifying objects. What do you want to do here - create a new list with new objects, or modify the members of `inputDto`? How are you accomplishing this now?

Comment: Also, why isn't row 3 in conflict with row 1 & 2 having matching `Userid` and `Attribute1`?

Comment: 3rd row is not conflicting because Country is Australia for that user and This is not conflicting with any of country for that user.

Comment: we are checking for conflicts for combination of 
U1 US(country)* Item1(Attribute)*
U1 UK Item2 
U1 Australia Item1